# Transposing and Untransposing a String in java

Tags: java, string, transpose

I have been working on two methods that will Transpose and Untranspose a String respectively. The solutions that I have come up with both work to the best of my knowledge. I just want to know if I could have solved these problems in a simpler way. My code seems like it is too long for the task that is being performed. The first method, transpose(), will take a String as a parameter and transpose it. If "bridge" is entered, the output will be "bergid". Likewise, with the unTranspose() method, if the user enters "bergid", the output will be "bridge".

```
  public void transpose( String s )
  {
      String t = ""; 
      int end = s.length() - 1;


        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length()  / 2; i++ )
        {
            t += Character.toString( s.charAt( i ) ) + Character.toString( s.charAt( end ) );
            end--;
        }
        // Lenth of String is odd
        if ( s.length() % 2 == 1 )
        {
            // add character in middle of String to the end of the new String
            t+= Character.toString( s.charAt( s.length() / 2 ) );
        }

        System.out.println( t );
  }

    public void unTranspose( String s )
    {
    String t = ""; 

      // Length of String is odd
      if ( s.length() % 2 == 1 )
      {
      for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2 )
      {
        t+= Character.toString( s.charAt( i ) );
      }

      for ( int i = s.length() - 2; i > 0; i -= 2 )
      {
        t += Character.toString( s.charAt( i ) );
      }

         System.out.println( t );
      }



   // Length of String is even
   else if ( s.length() % 2 == 0 )
   {
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i+=2 )
    {
       t+= Character.toString( s.charAt( i ) );
    }

    for ( int i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i -= 2 )
    {
        t+= Character.toString( s.charAt( i ) );
    }


    System.out.println( t );
}
   }
```

My code looks horrible. I'm still not used to formatting my code correctly. Please bear with me.

Thanks for your time

---

#### Definition

```
         transpose
         --------->
"123Xcba"            "1a2b3cX"
        <-----------
        untranspose
```

Comment: what does transposing a string mean?

Comment: Basically, if I have a String, "bridge", it turns it into "bergid". I take the first character of the String and concatenate it with the last character. Then I take the second character and concatenate it with the second to last character and so on. The results of these individual concatenations are concatenated together.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Recursion**

```
public static String transpose(String str) {

    if (str == null || str.length() == 1 || str.length() == 2) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return str.substring(0, 1) + str.substring(str.length() -1, str.length()) + transpose(str.substring(1, str.length() -1) );
    }
}

public static String untranspose(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 1 ||str.length() == 2) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return  str.substring(0, 1) + untranspose(str.substring(2, str.length())) + str.substring(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution has a nice symmetry.

```
public static String transpose(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.setLength(s.length());
    for (int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1, x = 0; i <= j; ) {
        sb.setCharAt(x++, s.charAt(i++));
        if (i > j) break;
        sb.setCharAt(x++, s.charAt(j--));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String untranspose(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.setLength(s.length());
    for (int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1, x = 0; i <= j; ) {
        sb.setCharAt(i++, s.charAt(x++));
        if (i > j) break;
        sb.setCharAt(j--, s.charAt(x++));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This makes it obvious that *the logic between the two methods are identical*; the only difference is that:

- In `transpose`, `i` and `j` are read indices, `x` is a write index
- In `untranspose`, `i` and `j` are write indices, `x` is a read index (i.e. it's the other way around)

It's really quite simple:

- `i` always goes from beginning to middle of string
- `j` always goes from end to middle of string
- `x` always goes from beginning to end of string
- If the input is of odd length, inevitably `i == j` eventually

  - At that point you only need `i`, so `break`

---

[Lalith came up with the first recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626640/transposing-and-untransposing-a-string-in-java/2629425#2629425); this one is essentially the same, with minor modification:

```
public static String transpose(String s) {
  int L = s.length();
  return (L < 2) ? s
    : s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(L-1, L) + transpose(s.substring(1, L-1));
}

public static String untranspose(String s) {
  int L = s.length();
  return (L < 2) ? s
    : s.substring(0, 1) + untranspose(s.substring(2, L)) + s.substring(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my response to this - The main issue I saw with your code is you creating Strings as temporary objects in multiple areas of the code - This makes it very inefficient as well as very slow. The other issue is that you want to externalize all you can from the loops.
I have compiled it and run it and it works.

```
package com.rch.test;

public class Transposer
{
    public static String transpose(String s)
    {
        int length = s.length();
        int end = length - 1;

        StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        {
            t.append(s.charAt(i));
            t.append(s.charAt(end));
            end--;
        }

        // Length of String is odd
        if (length % 2 == 1)
        {
            // add character in middle of String to the end of the new String
            t.append(s.charAt(length / 2));
        }
        return t.toString();
    }

    public static String unTranspose(String s)
    {
        int length = s.length();
        StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();

        if (length % 2 == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
            {
                t.append(s.charAt(i));
            }

            for (int i = length - 2; i > 0; i -= 2)
            {
                t.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        else if (length % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                t.append(s.charAt(i));
            }

            for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i -= 2)
            {
                t.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return t.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String testString = "bridge";
        String transposedString = Transposer.transpose(testString); 
        String finalString = Transposer.unTranspose(transposedString);

        System.out.println("1)" + testString);
        System.out.println("2)" + transposedString);
        System.out.println("3)" + finalString);
    }
}
```

Output :
1)bridge
2)bergid
3)bridge

Answer (score 0):

had a quick shot at doing your transpose method using a StringBuilder which usually makes these kind of operations simpler. This seems to work with your bridge example and also Strings of odd length.

```
public static void transpose( String s ) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for( int i=1; i<sb.length(); i=i+2 ) {          
        sb.insert( i, sb.charAt( sb.length()-1 ) );         
        sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length()-1 );
    }

    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
}
```

Should give you enough ideas to implement the untranspose method yourself :+)

Comment: This is `O(N^2)` due to shifts due to `insert`. And the way `sb` is shrinking after each iteration makes it overly complicated to evaluate the condition of termination.

Comment: @polygenelubricants - yes, thanks for pointing out that an `insert` is actually quite inefficient. You made me did into the javadocs for that one. I'll admit my main aim was to see how few lines of code I could do it in :+)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does not require different behavior based upon whether the length of the string is even or odd.

```
public static String transpose(String in)
{
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<in.length(); ++i)
    {
        out.append(in.charAt(i));
        out.append(in.charAt(in.length() - i - 1));
    }
    return out.substring(0, in.length());
}

public static String untranspose(String in)
{
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<in.length(); i+=2)
    {
        out.append(in.charAt(i));
    }
    StringBuilder reversedSecondHalf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=1; i<in.length(); i+=2)
    {
        reversedSecondHalf.append(in.charAt(i));
    }
    out.append(reversedSecondHalf.reverse());
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Wow, after seeing so many good solutions, i feel terrible about my code :( Thanks for the different responses. I believe it helps to see different approaches to a problem.

Comment: @Will, I would not worry too much about the elegance of your code.  From my experience, I have found that I often waste too much time trying to improve the elegance of the code when all that is ultimately important is the functionality of the code.  I would recommend that you focus your attention more on making solid tests for the code.  If the code passes the tests, it is sufficient.  The only problem that I see with what you wrote is the excessive use of String concatenations--which can be done more efficiently with something like StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to simplify the `transpose` method a bit:

```
public static String transpose(String s)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int i = 0;
   int length = s.length() - 1;
   while(i < length - i)
   {
      sb.append(s.charAt(i)).append(s.charAt(length - i));
      i++;
   }
   if(i == length - i) sb.append(s.charAt(i));
   return sb.toString();
}
```

**Update**

Tried my luck with untranspose -

```
public static String untranspose(String s)
{
   StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
   StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
   int length = s.length();
   int iopp = (length % 2 == 0) ? length - 1 : length - 2;
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 2, iopp -= 2)
   {
      sb1.append(s.charAt(i));
      if(iopp >= 0) sb2.append(s.charAt(iopp));
   }
   return sb1.append(sb2).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that shows the symmetry between transposing and untransposing.

```
public static String transpose(String in)
{
    int length = in.length();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in);
    for (int pos=1; pos<length; pos+=2)
    {
        swapCharacters(out, length-1, pos);
    }
    return out.toString();
}

public static String untranspose(String in)
{
    int length = in.length();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in);
    for (int pos=length-1-(length%2); pos>0; pos-=2)
    {
        swapCharacters(out, pos, length-1);
    }
    return out.toString();
}

private static void swapCharacters(StringBuilder string, int oldPos, int newPos)
{
    char c = string.charAt(oldPos);
    string.deleteCharAt(oldPos);
    string.insert(newPos, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression can be quite short without becoming too difficult to understand.

```
/** Convert ABCDefg to AgBfCeD */
public static String transpose(String s){
    char[] ts = new char[s.length()];
    int i = 0, j = ts.length;
    for( int k = 0 ; k < ts.length ; k++ ){
        ts[k] = s.charAt(k%2==0 ? i++ : --j);
    }
    return new String(ts);
}
/** Convert AgBfCeD to ABCDefg */
public static String untranspose(String ts){
    char[] s = new char[ts.length()];
    int i = 0, j = ts.length();
    for( int k = 0 ; k < ts.length() ; k++ ){
        s[k%2==0 ? i++ : --j] = ts.charAt(k);
    }
    return new String(s);
}
```